# Why does $\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^m-1 = e^r-1$?

Tags: limits

When calculating Continuous compounded rate, when $m$ tends to infinite, the equation says that the effective rates is $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^m-1 = e^r-1$$
But I don't understand where $e^r$ comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is one of the equivalent definitions of the [Exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition).

Comment: You are welcome. Do not really bother about where it comes from, just use it when you need it.